# PHP regex preg_match_all: Capturing text between multiple square brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need to capture some string arrays.. and i've been trying but i can't :$

i've this in my code:

```
<?php
$feed = "[['2013/04/03',8.300],['2013/04/04',8.320],['2013/04/05',8.400]]";
preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]/",$feed,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

and is returning:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [['2013/04/03',8.300]
            [1] => ['2013/04/04',8.320]
            [2] => ['2013/04/05',8.400]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ['2013/04/03',8.300
            [1] => '2013/04/04',8.320
            [2] => '2013/04/05',8.400
        )

)
```

how can i make with preg_match_all or preg_split.. or whatever method is needed to return one array of elements like the $matches[1][1] or $matches[1][2]??

i mean the format of each element should be:

```
'2013/04/05',8.400
```

hope to be clear :)

and thanks in advance!!

Comment: I might be completely wrong here, but the example looks like a valid JSON array. Wouldn't it be much easier to do `json_decode` and then just use it as a regular array?

Comment: You may use `(?<=^\[|,)\[(.*?)\]`.

Comment: or make your regex more specific `\[('\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}',\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\]`

Comment: hamza!! that second returned array is exactly what i need! it's possible to get that in just one array?

Comment: @lizaaard Sorry but that's how `preg_match_all()` works, so you have to do something like `$array = $matches[1]`;

Comment: Relevant info: [How to escape special characters in building a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19176024/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This text appears to be in fairly normalized format, ala JSON. It's entirely possible to avoid reg matching and parse this with **json_decode**, albeit some minor transformations have to be made.

```
// original input
$text = "[['2013/04/03',8.300],['2013/04/04',8.320],['2013/04/05',8.400]]";

// standard transformation to correct ' and / characters
$text = str_replace( array('/', "'"), array('\/', '"'), $text );

// let native PHP take care of understanding the data
$data = json_decode( $text );
```

This gives you the array of arrays, containing your dates and values. `print_r( $data );` gives:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 2013/04/03
        [1] => 8.3
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 2013/04/04
        [1] => 8.32
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => 2013/04/05
        [1] => 8.4
    )
)
```

The transformations are replacing `/` to `\/` and `'` to `"` to make the string JSON-compliant. Or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<?php
$feed = "[['2013/04/03',8.300],['2013/04/04',8.320],['2013/04/05',8.400]]";
preg_match_all('~\[\K[^][]+~', $feed, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Your solution has an opening bracket in the first match. [0] => ['2013/04/03',8.300

Comment: that's pretty much what i need.. just the first element has the [ square braket.. but maybe i can clean that when looping... but it's possible to remove it?

Comment: @lizaaard: Ihave forgotten the open square bracket in the class. It's corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If it would happen to be **not** a valid json, you could do simple manipulations with strings.

```
$arr = explode("],[", trim($str, " []"));
```

Output would be an array of with elements similar to this: `"'2013/04/03',8.300" , "'2013/04/04',8.320"`

This will work *times* faster than approach using RegExp methods.