# Newtosoft.Json Bad JSON escape sequence: \v.

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using Newtosoft.Json for parsing JSON, which is quite normal in C# :)

Unfortunately I got a json string like following to parse:

```
{"data": {"str_1": "&#39; \u001e\v \u0003\u001f&quot;\u0003\u001d %\b)\v#"}}
```

Calling `JObject.Parse(aboveLine)` gives me an error like 
`Bad JSON escape sequence: \v. Path 'data.str_1', line 1, position [number].`
`\v` is a sign for vertical line.

Is there a way how can I parse above json without exception?

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @EZI I don't understand your comment

Comment: Garath, I say it is not a valid json. So You can't parse it. If you are getting it from some service ask them.

Comment: @EZI it is a valid JSON. Look at specification here: https://www.json.com/json-object or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string

Comment: Garath, Don't post me specs. Have you tried the link I posted. It is a json validator. Use it and see by yourself. Why don't you read and try the comments seriously. They are to help you.

Comment: @EZI I tried it. And it doesn't work for above string. But what should be my conclusion after this: my string is bad or  jsonlint.com doesn't implement whole specification? That is why I check specification and send you comment with information.

Comment: Then double-check. http://json2csharp.com/ or http://json.parser.online.fr/ What now? It is invalid. What is the source  of it. If you, then check your code. If not, then nothing you can do about it (other than some silly string operations to fix it).

Comment: I understand that SOME parses claims that is not invalid. That is why I check specification. And I change parser: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/489 . I hope my pull request will be accepted. BTW http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html claims it is a valid JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the specification and I found that '\v' is a valid JSON. The specification is available here: https://www.json.com/json-object#object-with-strings

I also checked the source code an it does not support '\v'. That is why I created pull request which I hope will be merged into Newtonsoft.Json: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/489

**Update**

Unfortunately for me http://json.com is WRONG and `\v` is not a valid backlash char in JSON. The [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) specifies all of them and `\v` is not in it :(
I added comment about this on http://json.com

**Update 2**

I described this story on my blog with all details. If you are interested just chek it out: http://stapp.space/bad-json-escape-sequence-v/

Comment: Interesting.  According to [json.org](http://json.org/) and the [ECMA JSON spec document](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) `\v` is not valid in JSON strings.  [RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) also does not have `\v`.

Comment: You are right. But I do not understand why json.com allows `\v`

Comment: Perhaps json.com isn't the "official" spec.

Comment: @BrianRogers Unfortunately you are right. According to RFC 4627(JSON spec) `\v` is not a valid part of JSON

Comment: json.org is the official/original website.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I know. But json.com have a bug which adds me day of work :( Anyway I add a comment. I hope they will fix it. Moreover some validators (like  http://freeformatter.com/json-validator.html) accept this char

Answer (score 0):

Use `\u000B` (vertical tab) instead of `\v` and you'll have a valid JSON.

> \v is a sign for vertical line

`\u007C` is the vertical line |

Comment: I do not produce JSON. I know I can replace it, but it doesn't look good