# Json Special Characters

Tags: json

I have a json object which contains some values that include some special chracter. For example `{UserName":"UserTest","Password":"OImqNlK/tLwUzKnt1rA1OA=="}`

I use it as an object parameter to call to web Api but I can't get it on Api server.

it works fine if I remove the special characters. For example:

```
{UserName":"UserTest","Password":"OImqNlKtLwUzKnt1rA1OA"}
```

Please help me fix it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First page when I put "Json Special Characters" into google : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string)

To be concrete to your question, this is the way

```
{UserName":"UserTest","Password":"OImqNlK\/tLwUzKnt1rA1OA=="}
```