# How do I [JSON.parse] a unc path?

Tags: javascript, json, unc

I'm trying to get a filename from the server to my client and the slashes are driving me insane.

If I have a fully qualified file path that is

`\\machine\share\inga.baz`

and I want this to be available on a JSON object on the client

1) what format needs to come in to allow JSON.parse to generate

```
var file = {"path":"\\machine\share\inga.baz"};
var filepath = file.path;
//filepath = "\\machine\share\inga.baz"
```

with no client-side conversion of the incoming string?

2) what changes need to be done client-side to sanitize the string such that

```
var filepath = file.path;
```

actually contains a resolvable resource name?

Comment: I think you need four slashes for each one like: `file = JSON.parse('{"path":"\\\\\\\\machine\\\\share\\\\inga.baz"}');`

Comment: I suspect just [escaping the path string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string) is all you need...

Comment: Your JSON is simply not properly encoded.

Comment: ...wait. I need 4 slashes per slash? ...that did it. (don't understand how this is a bad question though. If it's a dup, link)

Comment: each slash escape the next character, but as there is a string representation inside another string representation, you will need to double the doubled slashes

Comment: Yeah...I need to `json = JSON.parse(...); json = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 2); json = json.replace(/\\\\/g,'\\');` That gets me what I need. Found myself in slash soup but I was trying to solve the problem in the wrong area of processing and didn't have anybody to bounce ideas off of.