# How to use back slash in android json

Tags: java, android, json

I had a scenario where I need to give back slash for a key in JSON put method like below

```
json.put("path" , " \\abx\2010\341\test.PDF");
```

The value I gave for path key shows error.

How to handle this case?

Comment: The answers below are mostly correct, except to have double-slashes at the beginning, they'll both need to be escaped, a la: `\\\\abx`

Answer (score 2):

You need to write double slash instead of one: `\\`
So your code become:

```
json.put("path" , " \\\\abx\\2010\\341\\test.PDF");
```

You can learn more about escaping special characters [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19176131/6450941).

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
json.put("path" , "\\abx\\2010\\341\\test.PDF");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `\`.

Try `json.put("path" , " \\abx\\2010\\341\\test.PDF");`

You can learn more about it under [Escape Sequences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Answer (score 0):

double \\ = single \ in string ""

```
json.put("path","\\abx\\2010\\341\\test.PDF");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show like this, JSON file should be as below.

**"path" : " \\abx\2010\341\test.PDF"**

JSON also \ represent as \ in java special characters. Then java code should be as below.

`json.put("path" , " \\\\abx\\2010\\341\\test.PDF");`