# Unable to pass a value which contains %45 to a REST API

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, json, json.net

I am facing a problem inside my ASP.NET MVC 5 application.

I am passing the following JSON to a third party API, which include a password value :-

```
"{\"operation\":{\"Details\":{\"RESOURCENAME\":\"123\",\"ACCOUNTNAME\":\"test45\",\"PASSWORD\":\"123%456t\",\"createAccount\":{\"operation\":{\"Details\":{\"ACCOUNTLIST\":[]}}}}"
```

Now the problem is that inside the 3rd party system the API will save the password `123%456t` as `123E6t`.

Can anyone advice on this please? Is this a problem inside the 3rd party API or a problem that I need to handle from my side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is definitely a server side problem. The percent sign is [not a special character in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19176131/993547).

Deserializing your JSON with JSON.NET yields the expected result: `123%456t`.

I think they call `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` or something similar on the JSON as a whole or a part of it, since that yields `123E6t`.

Comment: So, as a forward-preventative measure, would you say to try and `UrlEncode()` the JSON, thus to counteract the possible `UrlDecode` the other end?

Comment: That sounds dangerous, but it is worth the try if they don't cooperate.

Comment: Noted. Just out of interest, I guess Newtonsoft's `JsonConvert` would output the same result?

Comment: @PatrickHofman so you mean it is a problem inside the 3rd party API ? now i am using JSON.net to construct my above json object..

Comment: Yes, I do. @johnG Your JSON looks okay. Are you sure you don't wrap it yourself?

Comment: @PatrickHofman now when i pass the password as 500%600 it will be saved as 500`0 so not sure if i can do any work around for this ?

Comment: @PatrickHofman so can you advice if my above json object is constructed correctly ? is so then i need to contact the 3rd party company to fix the problem ?

Comment: As said before "Yes, I do. @johnG Your JSON looks okay. Are you sure you don't wrap it yourself?"

Comment: @PatrickHofman I do not wrap it by my self... i use JSON.Net .... to serialize and deserialze the josn object

Comment: @GeoffJames can you please advice why i need to use UrlEncode() ?? and is this a problem from my side or from the 3rd party api side ?

Comment: @PatrickHofman now generally speaking is decoding the received json a correct approach to follow ? i mean seems from the result we are getting that the 3rd part API is decoding the json i am sending  .. so is decoding the passed json object a correct approach  from the 3rd part API ??? and should i be encoding the passed json (i do not think so)??

Comment: @johnG - I should imagine that the issue is being caused at the 3rd party API's end, like Patrick has already pointed out - with the possibility alluded to in this answer, it might be worth trying `var encodedJson = WebUtility.UrlEncode(json);` to see if it remedies the problem - if so, you know that the 3rd party is `UrlDecode()`ing the string the other end. This is not, however a good practice. Best solution would be to speak to the developers who work on the API to see what their suggestion is etc.

Comment: @GeoffJames but the problem with Url.Encode is that some values such as password@123 will be populated correctly inside the 3rd party  system.. so if i am going to encode the password@123 it will no longer work is this correct ? as it will be populated correctly out of the box ..

Comment: @GeoffJames now you mentioned "you know that the 3rd party is UrlDecode()ing the string the other end." but according to the API standards ,, should the 3rd party API decode the json i am sending ???

Comment: AFAIK the `@` character does not need to be encoded, and is fine as-is - which might explain why "`password@123`" works OK. I'm not aware of any "API Standards" (best practices, maybe - but it's not mentioned anywhere I can see). The only best-fit hard-and-fast rule for API devs to follow is to document their API to the hills, so that users that consume it know exactly how to compile request and send/receive data. Ergo, ensure that it's not in some tiny print in their documentation, and speak to one of them if possible, to see what's going on :)

Comment: @GeoffJames i totally agree with you , i send them an email with all the cases i faced ,, hopefully to get a respond from them soon.. But since there is not a standard for the API (generally speaking) ,, so it is not a surprise that they might be expecting the json in encoded format ,, although inside their API documentation they never mention this. this is correct ?

Comment: I hope they will sort this out for you. Good luck!

Comment: @PatrickHofman they replied back that i need to set the content type header as url encoded format which should fix them.currently i am using the following webclient class to upload the json object :- using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
                {
                    string url = currentURL + "resources?AUTHTOKEN=" + pmtoken;
                    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
                    
                    crudoutput = wc.UploadString(uri, "INPUT_DATA=" + data);
                }

Comment: I don't understand what they expect. The code looks okay.

Comment: Why do you do `INPUT_DATA=`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman this is how the json object should be formatted .. what they expect is to have my above json object to be url encoded ,,, such as wheh i encode using the following website http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: So it isn't a JSON request, it is a form encoded request. Then you should indeed use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` around the JSON part.

Comment: @PatrickHofman it is a Post request to the API as the json object i am sending is actually used to add a new resource inside the API ... so yes it is a Post request.. this is the API am talking about https://www.manageengine.com/products/passwordmanagerpro/help/restapi.html#createresource

Comment: @PatrickHofman now i try the following var encodedJson = WebUtility.UrlEncode(data); then i am going to send the encodedJson instead of sending the data object directly ,, and now i can see that my data is being populated correctly inside the API where 500%600 is going to be saved as 500%600 ... so should this be fine ?

Comment: @PatrickHofman but on your first comments you mentioned the following about using UrlEncode()  "That sounds dangerous, but it is worth the try if they don't cooperate." ,, so can i know why it is sound dangerous ?

Comment: @GeoffJames now based on your suggestion i used <<var encodedJson = WebUtility.UrlEncode(json);>> and i was able to send values such as 123%456t to the 3rd part api .. but you mentioned that "This is not, however a good practice." so can you mention why you consider url encoding my json is not a good practice ? now when i contact the 3rd party company they mentioned that i need to "set the content type header as url encoded format " ...

Comment: @johnG Just to clarify - what I meant was, that it doesn't seem to be convention that I've seen a lot of APIs use. This doesn't mean to say that it shouldn't be done - at the very least it *needs* to be documented somewhere with the API documentation to specify what is necessary when compiling and sending request. Glad you've got it working :)

Comment: @GeoffJames now they mentioned that i do not need to encode the json object manually using WebUtility.UrlEncode(json) ...  i need only to set the content type header as url encoded format  .. but not sure how i can do this operation inside WebClient UploadString ??

Comment: @johnG Off the top of my head it would be something like `client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` when you've created the `client`

Comment: @GeoffJames i tried this but did not work, as i will get the same problem that the data will be saved wrongly inside the 3rd party API..  i open another question regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640292/unable-to-encode-my-json-object-insdie-my-webclient-uploadstring-using-headers