# Unable to encode my JSON object inside my WebClient UploadString using Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC 4 web application and I need to post a JSON object to a 3rd part API. Now I need my JSON data to be encoded by setting the content type to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as mentioned inside the API documentations. so I tried the following by specifying the `Content-Type` as `wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";` :

```
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mainresourceinfo); 
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
{
    string url = currentURL + "resources?AUTHTOKEN=" + pmtoken;
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);

    //  wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    crudoutput = wc.UploadString(uri, "INPUT_DATA=" + data);
}
```

but still the data is not being encoded .. and if I send a value such as `123%456` inside my JSON string, it will be saved as `123E6t` inside the 3rd part system. now as a workaround i have manually encoded the JSON object using  `WebUtility.UrlEncode(data)` before sending it to the 3rd part API, and I can see that the values such as `123%456` will be saved correctly ...
but I do not want to be manually encoding the data ,, I want to set the content type to specify the encoding ...is this possible?

Comment: i see you want to post JSON data, shouldn't be `contentType="application/json"` ?

Comment: @Turbot but i want to encode the values inside my json object ??? is this possible ?

Comment: have you try to set your request `Content-Type=application/json` to see if it works ?

Comment: @Turbot yes originally i was using this  wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json" .... but i faced a problem when passing values such as "500%600" ... so i am trying to find a way to encode my data before sending it ..

Comment: Why don't you want to manually encoding the data?

Comment: you don't need to manually encode the data if the endpoint are compliance with the content-type you requested. are you sure the endpoint accept application/json ?

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
```

and try to set charset

```
wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
crudoutput = wc.UploadString(uri, "INPUT_DATA=" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
```

`Charset` is specifying the character encoding of the document. Default charset for `HTTP 1.1` is ANSI because ANSI is identical to [`ISO-8859-1`](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_8859.asp). 

Alse `WebClient.Encoding` by default is set to `Encoding.Default` that means you get ANSI code page. All Default encodings lose data, so, you might use UTF-8 instead.

So, if you set charset it does not mean that all content have to be encoded as Unicode, but it does mean that these documents can only contain characters defined by Unicode. It means you also need to save your content as UTF-8. In that case you can use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`

Comment: can you please advice what is the differecnes between setting the Content-Type and specifying the encoding  (wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;)? is specifying the encoding enough? or i need to use both of them ? and why you are using Encoding.UTF8.GetString() also , i think wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; will encode the data no need to Encoding.UTF8.GetString() ??is this correct?

Comment: @johnG Please see my updates. And please try  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as well. Just wondering to know the result. [Some](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations) info that can be helpful

Comment: but i can not understand why you are using UTF8 encoding twice ? one inside "Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)" and the other inside "wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;" could this lead to duplicate UTF8 encoding ???

Answer (score 2):

**Try this :**

```
                using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                string url = "URL";
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                string serialisedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                string response = client.UploadString(url, serialisedData);
            }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,, but can i know what are the differences between your approach and my approach ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`WebClient.UploadValues(Uri, NameValueCollection)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144243(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It will automatically do all stuff for you. You don't even need to specify a `Content-Type` header because it sends `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default.

Here is an example:

```
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mainresourceinfo); 
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
{
    string url = currentURL + "resources?AUTHTOKEN=" + pmtoken;
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);

    var body = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "INPUT_DATA", data }
    };
    crudoutput = wc.UploadValues(uri, body);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This how I impliment my post method

```
public static string Post(Exchange exchValues, string url)
{
  WebClient wc = new WebClient();
  wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
  return wc.UploadString(url, "POST", Json.Stringify(exchValues));
}
```

This sent 123%456 and the data don't convert to 123%456 ,I 'm use ASP.net Web API ,Json.Stringify use .net Json serialization

Also I face same problem when I try to use GET method the password parameter contain % character and the Api keep decode it so 123$45 decode to  123E6 
so I just replace % to %25 and it 's work

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("123%456".Replace("%","%25"));
```

Here some links help me [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers(v=vs.110).aspx) , [ASCII Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem with a 3rd party API. It took a while before I found the solution and all the other answers already given here look a lot like the things I've tried and did not work.
What worked for me was the UploadDataAsync. In my case special characters (é, ü, ã etc) would cause an error when sending the json string to the API.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json");
    client.UploadDataAsync(new Uri(apiUrl), "POST", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
}
```