# How to parse json escaped string with Python 3.0

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a bunch of json escaped strings, for example

```
str = "what a war\/what a peace"
```

(the escape doesn't limit to slash "/")

I want to parse it to

```
"what a war/what a peace"
```

How can I do it with python 3.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything stopping your from using the built-in `replace` on string instances?

```
s = "what a war\/what a peace"
r = s.replace('\\', '')
print(r)
'what a war/what a peace'
```

As an addendum, I know this in an example of what you want to do but, refrain from using names like `str`, `list` et-cetera. You'll regret it later.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I fear there is other escape which is not covered by this replacement. is there?

Comment: According to [this q&a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string) `json` too uses `\` to escape things so I'm guessing you would be ok.