# Android : gson.toJson() doesn't give standard json

Tags: android, json, gson, android-parser

When i tried to convert `Object` to json format using `gson.toJson(myObject)` it gives me not standard json format

Output currently :
`{\"objects\":[],\"type\":\"price\"}`

what should i need is like this : `{"objects":[],"type":"price"}`

below how i convert my Object to json :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
                String dataJson = gson.toJson(MyObject);
                System.out.println("LOG : " + dataJson);
```

My question is : **How to make normal json format using `Gson`?** thanks.

Comment: where are you getting this json data from or creating from ?

Comment: json string is in that format only after parsing that will get delected http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string

Answer (score 0):

Hi R Besar,

```
        String json="{\\\"objects\\\":[],\\\"type\\\":\\\"price\\\"}";
        Log.d("TAG","Old Json: "+json);

        String newJson=json.replace("\\","");
        Log.d("TAG","New Json: "+newJson);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{\"objects\":[],\"type\":\"price\"}
{"objects":[],"type":"price"}
```

I think this will help you