# Error in the JQL Query: The character \'%\' is a reserved JQL character

Tags: node.js, jira, jira-rest-api

In jira I have a project called "Abc Def Management". When i tried to get all issues within this project Using rest Api, i am getting the following error.

```
errorMessages: [ 'Error in the JQL Query: The character \'%\' is a reserved JQL character. You must enclose it in a string or use the escape \'\\u0025\' instead.
```

I am entering my code below.

```
client.post("https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/auth/1/session", loginArgs, function(data, response){
        console.log('Response', response);
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('succesfully logged in, session:', data.session);
            var session = data.session;
            // Get the session information and store it in a cookie in the header
            var searchArgs = {
                headers: {
                    // Set the cookie from the session information
                    cookie: session.name + '=' + session.value,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                data: {
                    // Provide additional data for the JIRA search. You can modify the JQL to search for whatever you want.
                    jql: "project=Abc%20Def%20Management"
                }
            };
            // Make the request return the search results, passing the header information including the cookie.
            client.post("https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search", searchArgs, function(searchResult, response) {
                console.log('status code:', response.statusCode);
                console.log('search result:', searchResult);
            });
            // response.render('index', {
            // });
        }
        else {
            console.log("Login failed");
            // throw "Login failed :(";
        }
    });
```

How can i resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Use spaces instead of %20.

You're using a POST request which will have the jql in its body, not as part of the url. So it is not necessary to url encode anything.

Comment: I tried this  also, but won't work. If the name of the project is a single word like 'abc' , then also it doesn't produce any result.

Comment: Does your jql return any results if you try it out in the jira issue search?

Comment: @Appunni, you need to put the Project name in quotes, something like this: `jql = "Project=\"Abc Def Management\""`

Comment: For more details about which characters need to be escaped in a json string, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27516892/1453994

Comment: @GlennV yes i am getting result in jira issue search

Comment: @rorschach - tried this ...but getting error----
 errorMessages: [ 'The value \'Abc Def Management\' does not exist for the field \'project\'.'

Comment: @Appunni are you sure that is the correct name of the Project? Maybe there are trailing whitespaces or something? It should work just like that.

Comment: Does the user that you use to send the REST call have permission to view browse that project? If he does and the JQL works when you try it out with that same user in the issue search screen, then something is wrong with the authentication of your REST call. I'm not familiar with the client that you use, but I don't see any basic auth in your code either, so maybe that's what you're missing.

Comment: @GlennV The variable 'loginArgs' contains the basic authentication values. Authentication is  working correctly

Comment: @rorschach - yeah. am sure