# how to fetch record where a text colum with json data key contains an apostrophe

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a postgres database table named booking, which has a column summary of type text and the value is a json. I want to fetch all the rows in which the json key such as name has an apostrophe `'`

Such as (Magyl's Travels) in the sample below

```
"{
    'description' : 'Annual fees', 
    'name' : 'Business Name Magyl's Travels', 
    'amount' : 5000
},{
    'description' : 'Registration fees', 
    'name' : 'Business Name Magyl's Travels',
    'amount' : 15000
}"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape special characters in building a JSON string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string)

Comment: `where strpos(summary, '''')  > 0`

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Is this supposed to be an array with two objects?

Comment: Yap,true,an arrayof objects,any idea how i can achieve my task

Comment: The json is not valid, so you won't be able to use any of the postgres json functions, but you might be able to do something with [postgres regex functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html)