# Are escape sequences escaped in order or simultaneously in JSON?

Tags: json

Imagine I want the literal string "\u" stored in a JSON string.

[This answer provides a nice visual overview of escape sequences in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string#27516892), but it's not clear from its picture whether they are escaped at the same time or in order.

Consider the following JSON:

```
{
  "foo": "a\\u"
}
```

This ought - to me at least - be valid JSON, wherein `foo` contains the string `a\u`.

However `\u` is an escape sequence for Unicode characters and must - usually - be followed by four hexadecimal characters.

When I enter the same JSON through [Json Parser Online](http://json.parser.online.fr/), which I believe uses `JSON.stringify` yields the following error:  "\u must be followed by 4 hexadecimal characters".

I also tried typing the following into both Firefox's and Chrome's consoles:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + '{"foo": "a\\u"}' + ")"));
```

And both yield an Unicode escape sequence error.  Even the library [superobject for Delphi](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject) yields the same error (or actually, it just throws a JSON parse error).

Looking through the [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-8) on strings, it does mention these escape sequences, but no mention on order.

It seems to me that the JSON standard does not consider the following sequence `\\u`, or at least, the parsers don't handle it well.  If `\\` is escaped first, `\\u` becomes `\u` and `\u` will be wrong.  If `\u` is escaped first, then it yields an error before it even gets to `\\`.

This is a particularly problem for [rich text in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842034/rich-text-in-json-string), because `\uc1` and `\uc2` are common control sequences in RTF.  The answer in question doesn't really touch on the subject, but the question also seems pretty much abandoned.

So a theoretical question would be:  How are (and how should) escape sequences be escaped?

And a more practical question would be:  How do I get the string literal `\u` into a JSON string beyond simply providing the Unicode sequence for either `\` or `u` (e.g. `a\u005Cu`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the escape sequence order in JSON?

Left to right. `\\u` contains the string *\u*.

> How do I get the string literal \u into a JSON string?

`"\\u"`

> When I enter the same JSON through Json Parser Online, which I believe uses JSON.stringify yields the following error: "\u must be followed by 4 hexadecimal characters".

This appears to be a bug in that tool.

A straight parse with a browser's JSON.parse works fine:

```js
// Note: The slashes have to be escaped to be put in the JS string literal.

var json = `{
  "foo": "a\\\\u"
}`;

console.log("JSON is: " + json);
var object = JSON.parse(json);
console.log("String in parsed object is: " + object.foo);
```

> ```
> var json = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + '{"foo": "a\\u"}' + ")"));
> ```

While `\` is an escape character in JSON, it is *also* an escape character in JavaScript string literals.

The JavaScript parser will convert `"a\\u"` to *a\u* **before** passing it to `eval()` which which will try to parse it as a JavaScript string literal (but an invalid one), **before** trying to convert it to JSON with `JSON.stringify`).

Comment: You are right that "\\\\u" works through `eval()` and `JSON.stringify()`, but if I try that sequence through the JSON Parser Online, that still yields an error.  And unfortunately, so does the superobject library I am using.  Perhaps this is an error in these libraries?

Comment: To answer my own comment, it appears that superobject cannot properly escape the sequences.  I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject/issues/28), but I doubt it'll get fixed, so for now we are seeking a more 'hacky' solution.

Comment: Actually, to make matters worse, I was wrong!  Superobject does work.  So it must be something else that's causing the error.  It's just that online tool that's broken.