# Sonar Issues/search API JSON result has single quotes

Tags: json, groovy, sonarqube

I'm using the sonarQube 6.4 web api to get a list of issues

> http://*sonar-server*:9000/api/issues/search?componentKeys=*Project_key*&sinceLeakPeriod=true&statuses=OPEN,REOPENED&types=BUG

This gives me a Json object which has single quotes,

> ..."message":"Make this function anonymous by removing its name:
>   **'function() {...}'**."...

Because of that highlighted content in the JSON I'm unable to process the JSON from Groovy.

Is the JSON returned by the sonar is valid ? 
if so, is there any way to process this kind of JSON in groovy. 
Let me know if the full JSON object is needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19176131/2662707

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam  I cannot process the JSON in Groovy. 
refer link https://groovy-playground.appspot.com/ 
So the JSON returned isn't valid right ?

Comment: The answer I linked to cites the specification which states that strings should be _double quoted_. There shouldn't be any need to escape single quotes. Just because you can't parse it in Groovy, doesn't mean it's wrong.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam My question is, is it a valid JSON string if it contains single quote, which is what the sonar API returns?

Comment: There's nothing in the spec that says it's invalid.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://json.org/ and https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/  the JSON response is valid. Single quotes and brackets `{}` must not be escaped. The issue comes from your Groovy parser.