# Issue with payload when passing user defined value to the body data

Tags: json, parsing, jmeter

When trying to pass the user defined value to the body content, I am getting error "message": "Bad JSON escape sequence: \S. ---- \r\nUnexpected character encountered while parsing value".
When passing complete raw payload through body data, I am not getting this error.

With User defined Variable,
  "customerBillingAddress":"26 Chestnut St\Suite 2B\Andover, MA 01810",

convert as  "   "customerBillingAddress":"26 Chestnut St\Suite 2B\Andover, MA 01810","

"\" is throwing error.

When testing with raw data, I am getting as it is in the payload.

```
     "customerBillingAddress":"26 Chestnut St\\Suite 2B\\Andover, MA 01810",
```

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `\` with `\\` and double quote `"` with `\"` as per JSON format guideline. Here I think you only need to escape `\` in your JSON payload like below .

`"customerBillingAddress":"26 Chestnut St\\Suite 2B\\Andover, MA 01810"`

Answer (score 0):

[You need to escape the following characters in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string):

```
\b  Backspace (ascii code 08)
\f  Form feed (ascii code 0C)
\n  New line
\r  Carriage return
\t  Tab
\"  Double quote
\\  Backslash character
```

In order to do this automatically you can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) available since [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31) like:

```
${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(vars.get('json')),)}
```

Demo:

[image: Groovy Escape JSON JMeter]