# Backslash in a STRING object

Tags: java, json, string, camera, sony

I want to write something like this 1/2

```
JSONObject requestJson =
                new JSONObject().put("method", "setShutterSpeed")
                        .put("params", new JSONArray().put('1' + "\\" + '/' + '2'))
                        .put("id", id()).put("version", "1.0");
        String url = findActionListUrl(service) + "/" + service;
```

But everything I tried fails.
I always receive something like that:

```
{"id":14,"method":"setShutterSpeed","version":"1.0","params":["1\\\/2"]}
```

I try to use the sony cameraremote API with this JSON call

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Where do you see the result? Printed? Saved to file? Returned to another client?

Comment: Sorry :-) its JAVA

Comment: I'm guessing you want the result to look like: `{"id":14,"method":"setShutterSpeed","version":"1.0","params":["1/2"]}` ?

Comment: I see the result in the debugger and I transfer this object to a digital camera but the API of the camera says it need to be formated like that 1\/2

Comment: and yes it needs to be ->   1 forwardslash backslash 2

Comment: `new JSONArray().put("1\\/2")` should be fine

Comment: unfortunately not. I tried this also. Result is {"id":35,"method":"setShutterSpeed","version":"1.0","params":["1\\\/2"]}

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack `new JSONArray().put("1\\/2")` would be exactly the same string that the OP has tried. (`'1' + "\\" + '/' + '2'` == `"1\\/2"`.) It looks like JSON is doing something special whenever it encounters a backslash. @Daniel You should add JSON or the API you are using to the tags, because this is not just a problem with Java strings; it's related to the JSON API.

Comment: Indeed, because JSON requires backslashes to escaped (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string), so `"1\\/2"` is sufficient (and yes I'm aware it's equivalent to the OP's string). The receiving client should be decoding accordingly

Comment: @ Klitos Kyriacou  thx for your hint. I added the information.  I try to use the Sony camera remote API

Comment: I think the client wants forward slashes to be escaped and your JSON encoder doesn't want to do that. You'll probably have to update the string manually or use a different JSON library.