# Include backslash in my test JSON - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, escaping, postman

I am testing an application where I wish to input some text into a textfield and see if the application accepts it or raises an error. I am using postman and reading from a json data file with my different entries.

I wish to include an entry like thisL

```
{
  "name": "namewith\test",
},
```

However using this I get an error:

```
Unexpected control character at 1:25
```

I have tried this:

```
{
  "name": "namewith\\test",
},
```

this:

```
{
  "name": "namewith\/test",
},
```

this

```
 {
    "name": "namewith'\'test",
 },
```

How can I include this backslash and not have it recognized as an escape character?

Comment: \t is a tab. Try \\test or \\\\test

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is `\\`

Your answer:

`{
  "name": "namewith\\test",
},`

should work. It works for me. Is there an object after this? That trailing comma could be a problem - unlike JS, JSON doesn't accept an extra comma at the end.

What error are you getting for this option.

Comment: Yeah, must have been the trailing comma, working now! Thanks Kevin.

Answer (score -1):

May this idea help.

```
var customerData = document.getElementById("inputText").val();
var json = {
   name: customerData
}
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json); //you get the content parsed
```