# Connection string parameter cannot be null

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, connection-string

I have an MVC Core application that works on my machine, where SQLEXPRESS is not a named instance. When I deploy it to IIS 7.5 on a remote machine, where it is a named instance, without changing the connection string:

```
"Server=localhost;Database=QuickShare;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

I get the following error:

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

Then I correct the connection string for the nameD instance:

```
"Server=localhost.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=QuickShare;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

I get the following error:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   connectionString

In the stack trace on the developer error page, highlighted is the following line from `Startup.cs`:

```
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

How does changing only the connection string go from an expected connection exception to a null parameter exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remeber that your configuration file is JSON which means certain characters need to be escaped, in this case it's the backslash. So from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string) you can see that you need to double up the backslash. For example:

```
"Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=QuickShare;......"
```