# extjs 4.2 - entity encoding with backslash e.g. '\1014'

Tags: extjs

The value "\1014" is coming from my database and I want to display it in an ExtJS Panel.

The problem is, it gets processed as an entity value, and "A4" is displayed instead

I don't want to have to do entity encoding on the back end.

I tried

```
Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode('\1014')
```

But this also returns "A4"

What is the correct way to encode such values on the front-end for display?

Comment: what is the problem please explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with ExtJS. This is a builtin feature of JavaScript and JSON. If you want to send the non-literal `\101` as JSON to the frontend, you have to escape the backslash correctly to the specs **in the backend**:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"test":"\\101","id":"extModel2-1"}}
```

If you don't escape the backslash, it will be converted to the appropriate literal immediately when it hits the frontend and is then indistinguishable from the letter `A`, so this is not revertible on the frontend.

[Relevant fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2g70)

[Relevant older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19176131/1827295)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse data using JSON.parse(response.reponseText) instead of Ext.decode