# Keeping newline \n as is in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, json, newline

I want to keep string values in my insert object as is

This works fine, the \n is kept

```
{insert: "erferferf\nerferferf"}
```

This

```
{insert: "\n\n\n"}
```

And this becomes a problem

```
{insert: "\n"}
```

it makes the string like this

```
    {insert: "


"}
```

I want the string to keep the "\n\n\n" rather than becoming a bunch of new lines

Comment: try using `.trim()`, it may solve your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape special characters in building a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string)

Comment: `JSON.stringify("\n\n\n").slice(1, -1)`

Comment: Simply put \ before \n. {insert: "\\n\\n\\n"}

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace()` to replace `\n` with `\\n`. If you leave `\n` in the variable, it is interpreted as a `next line character`. So, just replace it with `\\n`, thus effectively making it \ + n.

Here is an example to illustrate what I'm on about.

```js
string = "javascript\n";
console.log(string.replace("\n","\\n"));
data = {insert:string.replace("\n","\\n")};
console.log("From Object: "+data['insert']);

string = "\n"
console.log(string.replace("\n","\\n"));
data = {insert:string.replace("\n","\\n")};
console.log("From Object: "+data['insert']);
```