# Parse error when text is split on multi lines: "control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped"

Tags: json, jq

I'm getting a "parse error" when I split a text line on multiple lines and show the JSON file on screen with the command `jq . words.json`.

The JSON file with the text value on a single line looks like this

```
{
    "words" : "one two three four five"
}
```

The command `jq . words.json` works fine and shows the JSON file on screen.

But when I split the value "one two three four five" on two lines and run the same command I get a parse error

```
{
    "words" : "one two   
    three four five"
                   ^
}
```

> parse error: Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through
> U+001F must be escaped at line 3, column 20

The parse error points to the `"` character at the end of the third line.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you get that entire file back from the server, or just the `content` portion?  JSON doesn't allow newlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the JSON format is invalid. It should look like this:

```
{
    "words" : "one two \nthree four five"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

That's not valid JSON; JSON strings don't contain literal newlines. But you can do:

```bash
jq -Rnr '[inputs] | join("\\n") | fromjson | .choices[0].message.content' sample.json
```

Answer (score 2):

> The parse error points to the `"` at the end of the third line.

The way `jq` flags this error may be counterintuitive, but the error in the JSON *precedes* the indicated quote-mark.

If the error is non-obvious, **it may be that an end-quote is missing on the prior key or value**.  In this case, the value that matches the criteria `U+0000 through U+001F` could be `U+000A`, which is the [line feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

In the case of this question, the line feed was inserted intentionally.  But, unescaped, this is [invalid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27516892/86967).

Answer (score 2):

this is another option for user @randombits

```
cat sample.json | jq -R '.' | jq -s '.' | jq -r 'join("")' | jq -r '.choices[0].message.content'
```

Comment: Not sure of the logic here but this formula works and has saved my script since I have no control of the generated json.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape end of line in JSON:

```
{
  "words" : "one two\nthree four five"
}
```

Comment: Minor semantic nit: this is a string that includes an escape sequence that *represents* a newline character, rather than escaping a literal newline character.

Answer (score 1):

To convert the text with the multi-line string to valid JSON, you could use `any-json` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/any-json), and pipe that into jq:

```
$ any-json --input-format=cson split-string.txt
{
    "words": "one two three four five"
}
$ any-json --input-format=cson split-string.txt | jq length
1
```

For more on handling almost-JSON texts, see the jq FAQ: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#processing-not-quite-valid-json

Answer (score 0):

if you're the owner of the json and you want to avoid this type of problem, just encode your value with `base64` . Simple example:

Encode:

```
echo "one two \nthree four five" | base64
```

decode:

```
echo "my_base64_encoded" | base64 -d
```

you can also integrate this mechanism into your code directly :

- golang:https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/base64
- python:https://ioflood.com/blog/python-base64-encode/