# JSON.parse and JSON.stringify error on special character in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, stringify

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify($('.btn').attr('data-obj')))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-info user_action" data-action="edit_faqs" data-obj="{SysID:2,Artist:Json Mras,Song:I'm yours}" data-toggle="modal " data-target="#SongsModal
  "><i class="fa fa-edit "></i> Edit</button>
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string) but this is a little different in my case.

When I tried using JSON.stringify on the data I can see in the dev tools

```
//I want I'm Yours
"{\"Song\":\"I"
```

The data is stored in my database and I get it in ajax request and I want to use `JSON.stringify` to it because I will put it as a `data-*` on a button which will then be used when I click the button. On button click I want to use `JSON.parse` so I can iterate over it.

How to escape all special characters in `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

Error is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

That points to the `JSON.stringify`

[image]

Added a snippet but it didnt recreate problem so I added an image

Database:

[image]

Update:

I get the data from ajax request. After getting the data I use `data_array = JSON.stringify(data[i]);` then apply the data as `data-obj='" + data_array + "'`

Comment: Sorry, but I can't believe you. If you do `JSON.stringify("I want I'm Yours")`, you get the string `"I want I'm Yours"` (with double quotes), not `{\"Song\":\"I"`. JavaScript won't invent the word "Song", so the input is _clearly_ not what you say it is. If you have JSON-compatible data, running it through `stringify` and then `parse` is perfectly safe. The problem of the linked question was he started with bad JSON, then tried to run `parse` on it.

Comment: Can you show more code? I doubt`I want I'm Yours` became `"{\"Song\":\"I"` just through JSON.stringify

Comment: Also, there is no way to get "Unexpected end of JSON input" from `JSON.stringify`, only from `JSON.parse`

Comment: I will show what it looks like in dev give me a minute

Comment: @Amadan I added an snippet but it didnt recreate so I added images instead

Comment: You are not going to be able to stringify that because it is invalid JSON ... try to change the data-obj to   ;`{
 "SysID": 2,
 "Artist": "Json Mras",
 "Song": "I 'm yours"}`

Comment: @emineminems the data is from database after getting it from ajax I apply JSON.stringify to it so I can put it in button as data attribute. Your suggestion Im thinking about changing `'` before applying sa data-attribute Im still working on it

Comment: Also, for next time, please be very careful to give us exact information. In your question, `//I want I'm Yours` cannot correspond to `"{\"Song\":\"I"`; the content you showed in your code snippet `data-obj="{SysID:2,Artist:Json Mras,Song:I'm yours}"` is very different from what is shown in the image you lated posted from your console. It is pretty much impossible to answer questions based on wrong data, and in the extreme case it could get your question closed, with no answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not a problem with JSON, it's a problem with your misuse of HTML.

You inserted a raw string into a HTML attribute, probably from a template, possibly by doing something like

```
<button data-obj="<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>">
```

Or possibly in JavaScript

```
container.innerHTML = '<button data-obj="' + JSON.stringify(data) + '">';
```

so your quotes end up clashing with HTML's. You need to change your quotes into HTML entities; the minimum is changing double quotes `"` into `&quot;` if you are using double quotes around the HTML attribute (the most common scenario).

You have not told us how you insert the content into the HTML, so I can't tell you how to do it until you do clarify.

EDIT: Apparently you are building HTML in JavaScript by concatenation. In that case, the solution I showed would work:

```
container.innerHTML = '<button data-obj="' + data_array.replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + '">';
```

Or, if you're using single quotes to enclose the attribute (not commonly done, but certainly an option), you would need to change *those* to `&apos;` instead:

```
container.innerHTML = "<button data-obj='" + data_array.replace(/'/g, '&apos;') + "'>";
```

However, given that it's JavaScript we're talking about, and it can work with DOM, and DOM knows what's what... there's many other solutions. The most primitive one is to work with DOM directly:

```
let button = document.createElement('button');
button.setAttribute('data-obj', data_array);
container.appendChild(button);
```

When you do this, JavaScript manipulates the DOM directly, not HTML, so escaping is not needed.

A level above this would be to use a library like jQuery:

```
$('<button>').data('obj', data_array).appendTo('#container');
```

A level yet above that would be to use a library that employs data binding, like Angular, React, Vue, Ractive... where you would just set the value on your model, and the document automagically reflects that change.

Changing manually `"` into `&quot;` is only needed if you directly manipulate HTML.

Comment: I did the second one. I get the data from ajax request. After getting the data I use `data_array = JSON.stringify(data[i]);` then apply the data as `data-obj='" + data_array + "'` so solution is interchange the quotes? let me try it

Comment: No; if you're using JavaScript you _can_ change quotes, but it would be better to do it properly with DOM, since DOM will know what to do. Lemme write it out in the answer.

Comment: ok i will wait. I tried changing now the first half gets the error.

Comment: I see. Now I get what you mean. I think I will go with the first one. Im actually appending the button in a datatable so Im doing it like that. Let me try it I'll be back shortly

Comment: It did the job Thanks mate happy coding. Explanation is great