# How to fetch next URL from JSON using Bash

Tags: bash, curl

I have created a simple script to store response from a third party API

The request is like this..

```
https://externalservice.io/orders?key=password&records=50&offset=0
```

The response is as follows:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "engagement": {
        "id": 29090716,
        "portalId": 62515,
        "active": true,
        "createdAt": 1444223400781,
        "lastUpdated": 1444223400781,
        "createdBy": 215482,
        "modifiedBy": 215482,
        "ownerId": 70,
        "type": "NOTE",
        "timestamp": 1444223400781
      },
    },
  ],
  "hasMore": true,
  "offset": 4623406
}
```

If there is a **hasMore** attribute, I need to read the `offset` value to get the next set of records.

Right now I've created a script that simply loops over the estimated number of records (I believed there is) and thought incrementing the offset would work but this is not the case as the offset is not incremental.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..100}; do
    curl -s "https://externalservice.io/orders?key=password&records=50&offset=$i" >>outfile.txt 2>&1
done
```

Can someone explain how I can read continue the script reading the `offset` value until `hasMore=false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read a value from a json using the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) utility:

```sh
$ jq -r ".hasMore" outfile

true
```

Here is what you could use:

```sh
more="true"
offset=0
while [ $more = "true" ]; do
    echo $offset
    response=$(curl -s "https://example.com/orders?offset=$offset")
    more=$(echo $response | tr '\r\n' ' ' | jq -r ".hasMore")
    offset=$(echo $response | tr '\r\n' ' ' | jq -r ".offset")
done
```

Comment: Thanks, while this partially solves the question (re: if hasMore=true), the bigger issue is I need to read what the `offset` value. I cannot simply use an incremented value.

Comment: Sorry, totally missed that part of your question. I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the update, I seem to be getting a parsing error: `parse error: Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped at line 180, column 8`. I think its the way the bash is formatted, if I use the original snippet you provided it worked. I've tried wrapping `echo $response` like `echo "$response"` but that doesn't work.

Comment: I've also tried `curl -s 'https://example.com/orders?offset=0' | jq -r '.hasMore'`, this works without any errors.

Comment: Looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399819/bash-jq-parse-error-invalid-string-control-characters-from-u0000-through-u0?noredirect=1&lq=1, I'd try`echo $response | tr '\r\n' ' ' | jq`

Comment: Don't ```echo $response``` json stored in variable, it will lead to all sorts of problems. Main one being it will replace all your ```\n``` sequences within attribute values to actual newlines. Use ```printf "%s\n" "$response"``` instead.

Don't remove newlines with ```tr``` - that only covers the error (doesn't fix it) because ```echo``` modifies json to invalid format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jq utility to extract specific attribute from you json response:

```sh
$ jq -r ".hasMore" outfile

true
```

jq expects perfectly valid json input, otherwise it will print error.
Most common mistake is to `echo` json stored in variable. A mistake, because echo will interpret all escaped newlines in your json and will send unescaped newlines within values causing jq to throw `parse error: Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped at line` message.

To avoid modification to json (and avoiding an error) we need to use `printf` instead of `echo`.

Here is the solution without breaking json content:

```sh
more="true"
offset=0
while [ $more = "true" ]; do
    echo $offset
    response=$(curl -s "https://example.com/orders?offset=$offset")
    more=$(printf "%s\n" "$response" | jq -r ".hasMore")
    offset=$(printf "%s\n" "$response" | jq -r ".offset")
done
```