# Django REST framework not looking for URL encoded detail views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model whose Primary Key is a TextField. This is a minimalistic reproduction of my issue:

Model:

```
class Filename(models.Model):
    path = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
```

Serializer:

```
class FilenameSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Filename
        fields = '__all__'
```

View:

```
class FilenameViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Filename.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FilenameSerializer
```

I'm using a `DefaultRouter` for URLs. Here is the problem: If I sent 
`{"path":"test"}` with a `POST /filename/` I can perfectly retrieve my object with `GET /filename/test/` as you would expect. However, if I `POST /filename/` something like `{"path":"c:\\test"}` I would expect either `GET /filename/c%3A%5Ctest/` or `GET /filename/c%3A%5C%5Ctest/` to be the proper way to get it, but none of those works. Does anybody knows what's going on?

Update: The webserver logs show `Not Found: /filename/c:\test` so it's being decoded properly at some moment. Maybe some URL regex issue?

Comment: I doubt is very relevant for this question in particular, but python=3.7, django=2.1.2 and djangorestframework=3.8.2

Comment: The `path` simply stores "`test"`, so the query `SELECT * FROM filename WHERE path = 'C:\\test'` fails, hence nothing is returned. For the database this is just a string, whether that string "happens" to be a filepath is irrelevant.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm of course creating the c:\test object. The second POST with the json data is in the question too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was not with any URL encoded in general, but with the dot (%2E) in particular. The DefaultRouter() does not match the dots by default. This behavior can be modified setting the `lookup_value_regex` attribute in the ViewSet.

```
class FilenameViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Filename.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FilenameSerializer
    lookup_value_regex = '[^/]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you have to define the lookupfield , you can overide the get_object change string format to a norma text

```
class FilenameViewSet(ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Filename.objects.all()
   serializer_class = FilenameSerializer
   lookup_field = 'path'

def get_object(self):
   try:
      from urllib import unquote
   except ImportError:
      from urllib.parse import unquote
  path = unquote(kwarhs['path'))
  return self.get_queryset.get(path=path)
```

Comment: I tried, but it's not working neither. I don't think that's the issue as non-url-encoded files are found fine. By default the lookup_field should be the pk anyway.

Comment: By default the `lookup_field` is the primary key IIRC.

Comment: you can overide the get_object method

Comment: The get_object method is not even being called. The logs shows me `Not Found: /filename/c:\test` so django is decoding it properly.... maybe a URL path issue?

Answer (score 0):

if im getting your question correctly . you problem is with json format .
On adding escape character \  before special characters would resolve your issue.

see this link below:
[How to escape special characters in building a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string)

Comment: Hi babak, the JSON is working fine, the POST are successful. The issue is getting the object back via a GET request.

Comment: i think you can validate your return obj in your return call. try to use valid() in modelserializer.