# How to escape special characters programmatically while reading json in C#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jpath

In the json message, I have a field `Name` which can have a various combination of different special characters. Due to special characters, when I filter this property I get an error:

> Unexpected character while parsing path query: !

Value of this property is not fixed. Since the combination of Special characters is not known in advance I cannot apply a specific escape sequence while applying jpath to filter a property.

For eg: if `'Name': ''!!!',`then `$..[?(@Name== '\'!!!')]` will solve the problem. However the same field can also have values like `'Name': 'A!!!'`.In this case same escape sequence will fail.

```
 [Test]
    public static void Test()
    {
        string json = @"{'Type': 'Contoso',
             'Products': [
                 {
                 'Name': ''!!!',
                 'Price': 99.95
                 }]
                    }";
        var jobject = JToken.Parse(json);
        string name = (string) jobject.SelectToken("$..[?(@Name== ''!!!')]");

    }
```

The other possible combinations of `Name` are  `'Name': '!"!!'`,  `'Name': ''"!!'`,  `'Name': '$"!!'` , `'Name': '/"!!'`  `'Name': ',!!!'` etc.
Is there a generic way of escaping the special characters programmatically so that I can handle all the combinations?

Comment: What the problem with 'A!!!' value? It looks like correct string

Comment: There is no problem with 'A!!!' .. I meant to say the property "Name" can begin with non special characters as well, which does not require to escape.

Comment: So you only have problems with Name value, right?  Please add more examples of problem input, if any. Or the only possible case is when name value looks like `''some string'`?

Comment: @AleksAndreev  I have updated the other example inputs.

Comment: `'Name': ''!!!',` is invalid JSON.  If the string is intended to contain a single apostrophe, it needs to be escaped.  Otherwise, the duplicate apostrophe needs to be removed.

Comment: Single apostrophe in 'Name': ''!!!' is intended.  But it is not escaped currently and on that I have no control on it as I'm the consumer of this json. Is there a way wherein I can escape it while reading it or any other work arounds?

Comment: When present, will the unescaped single quote always be at the start of the string?  Will it always be in the value of `name`?  The only character causing you a problem is that unescaped single quote.  None of the other special characters are cause for concern.

Comment: @SKN - You ask, *How to escape special characters programmatically while reading json in C#?*, but is your real question *How to escape special characters **in string literals inside JsonPATH queries**?*  Your problem is with formatting the path passed to [`SelectToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm), right?

Answer (score 0):

This should auto-escape an unescaped apostrophe.  If the JSON contains multiple un-escaped apostrophes, it should recurse until all of them are fixed.

Really, though, you should contact whoever is generating the bad JSON and ask them to correct it.

```
private static JToken ParseWithAutoEscape(string json)
{
    try
    {
        return JToken.Parse(json);
    }
    catch (JsonReaderException ex)
    {
        if (!ex.Message.StartsWith("After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered:"))
            throw;

        var lines = json.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var badLine = lines[ex.LineNumber - 1];

        // contains the part of the line before the apostrophe
        var before = badLine.Substring(0, ex.LinePosition - 1);

        // contains the apostrophe and what comes after.
        var after = badLine.Substring(ex.LinePosition - 1);

        lines[ex.LineNumber - 1] = $"{before}\\{after}";
        json = String.Join("\n", lines);

        // try again.
        return ParseWithAutoEscape(json);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var jobject = ParseWithAutoEscape(json);
var name = jobject.SelectToken("$..[?(@Name== '\\'!!!')]");
Debug.WriteLine(name);
```

Note that the `'` needs to also be escaped in your query selector.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Amy for providing with the detailed solution..  I wouldn't have thought of this approach otherwise.. This solution solves part of my problem. the unsolved part is, after parsing it needs to save the value with escaped character, so that I can pass the same to the jpath without worrying the need for escaping....

Comment: Aren't you querying for a name known ahead of time?

Comment: Not always!... In real scenario, I would get the complete response from endpoint, then filter the name using jsonpath.. Then I will use the value thus obtained to perform some more operations... I would not know the value of name before hand...

Comment: Then I don't think you should be querying for a specific name, and instead should iterate over the array of products.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like Amy said, the json (string json) is the problem, not your jpath expression. It contains invalid json since `'Name': ''!!!'` is not valid json. You need to escape the single quote to `\'`.

It needs to look like this:

```
    string json = @"{'Type': 'Contoso',
         'Products': [
             {
             'Name': '\'!!!',
             'Price': 99.95
             }]
                }";
```

If you have further doubts about json escape sequences try to have at look at this:

[How to escape special characters in building a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string)

If what you really are talking about when you say "escaping special characters" is how to do a wildcard expression in JPath (i get this suspicion because you list a bunch of !!-ending patterns) then you might try something like this:

```
    string json = @"{'Type': 'Contoso',
         'Products': [
             {
             'Name': '\'!!!',
             'Price': 99.95
             }]
                }";
    var jobject = JObject.Parse(json);
    string name = (string)jobject.SelectToken("$.Products[?(@.Name =~ /.*!!$/i)].Name");
```

It will match a JavaScript regular expression, any name ending with !! (two exclamation marks).