# Visual Studio Code tasks.json issue with path in powershell

Tags: json, powershell, batch-file, visual-studio-code

I have an addon that runs a command everytime I hit save.
I get the following error when I try to run a batch file on save:

> The command autopush.bat was not found, but does exist in the current
>   location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current
>   location by default. If you trust this command, instead type:
>   ".\autopush.bat". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more
>   details.

My settings.json file:

```
{
    "saveAndRun": {
        "commands": [
          {
            "match": ".*",
            "cmd": "autopush.bat",
            "useShortcut": false,
            "silent": false
          }
        ]
      }
}
```

I am not sure about how I can add a dot and backslash to "autostart.bat"

I tried with ".\b autostart.bat" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I used the wrong escape character. I had to use `.\\autostart.bat` as described here: [How to escape special characters in building a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string)

```
\b  Backspace (ascii code 08)
\f  Form feed (ascii code 0C)
\n  New line
\r  Carriage return
\t  Tab
\"  Double quote
\\  Backslash character
```