# AWS CloudWatch Event Rule - Invoke Lambda with Parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using an AWS CloudWatch Event Rule to invoke a Python Lambda function based on Cron Schedule, which is working fine. Now can I pass a parameter into this Lambda function from CloudWatch Event Rule using AWS CloudFormation? Here is my cfn template:

```
Step 1: parameter.Schedule=cron(0 21 ? * * *)

Step 2: "Schedule": {
            "Description": "Schedule for the Lambda function (cron or rate)",
            "Type": "String"
         },
          
          
Step 3:  "funcInvokeRule": {
            "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
            "Properties": {
                "ScheduleExpression": {"Ref": "Schedule"},
                "Targets": [{
                    "Id": "funcScheduler",
                    "Arn": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["Function","Arn"]}
                }]
             }
          },
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Target`  property type  of `AWS::Events::Rule` has [Input](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-target.html#cfn-events-rule-target-input) parameter:

> Valid JSON text passed to the target. If you use this property, nothing from the event text itself is passed to the target.

There is also [InputTransformer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-target.html#cfn-events-rule-target-input) which you can use to transform existing input, by for example, adding extra values to it.

> Settings to enable you to provide custom input to a target based on certain event data. You can extract one or more key-value pairs from the event and then use that data to send customized input to the target.

Answer (score 1):

As @Marcin pointed out, the `Input` parameter of the `Targets` property is what you want. Keep in mind the format is JSON *text* so ensure you [escape special chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string). Here is an example using your CloudFormation resource:

```json
"funcInvokeRule": {
    "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
    "Properties": {
        "ScheduleExpression": {"Ref": "Schedule"},
        "Targets": [{
            "Id": "funcScheduler",
            "Arn": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["Function","Arn"]},
            "Input": "{\"foo\":\"val\",\"bar\":{\"baz\":\"nested_val\"}}"
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html), your cloudformation resource could be as simple as:

```
Resources:  
  EventRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: {EVENTNAME}
      Description: "ScheduledRule"
      ScheduleExpression: cron(0 21 ? * * *)
      State: "ENABLED"
      RoleArn: {ROLE}
```

Replacing **Name** and **RoleArn** with your own values.

*Note: Name is not a required parameter but does help identify your resources. However, as per the documentation, if you replace the resource in your cloudformation template you specify a new name.*

If you were then also going to use cloudformation for your [lambda using severless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-codeuri), personally I would then attached the rule to the lambda via permissions, that way you can attach up to 5 triggers on the rule without modifying the rule targets every time. e.g.

```
  Lambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName:{LAMBDANAME}
      Description: {Description}
      Role: {Role}
      Handler: {FileName}.lambda_handler
      Runtime: {x}
      CodeUri: {ObjectPath}
      MemorySize: {x}
      Timeout: {x}
  Lambdatrigger:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref Lambda
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: events.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !Ref EventRule
```

Comment: This example does not work. Reason: the last line "SourceArn: !Ref EventRule" will not be deployed by cloudformation. As the property name already suggests, you need the ARN, not the Rule ID. So use "SourceArn: !GetAtt EventRule.Arn"