# Line feed in OPENJSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I got a problem with `OPENJSON`.

```
DECLARE @X AS VARCHAR(1000) = CONCAT('[{"KEY":1, "VALUE": "A', CHAR(10) ,'B"}]')

SELECT
     *    
FROM
    OPENJSON(@X)  
    WITH (
        [KEY] INT 'strict $.KEY',
        [VALUE] VARCHAR(1000) 'strict $.VALUE'
    )
```

This doesn't work because I used a line feed (`char(10)`), how can I fix this? Carriage return (`char(13)`) doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Char(10) and char(13) are special characters in JSON and must be escaped. You can see this question here on how-to [How to escape special characters in building a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string)

To fix your current issue you can do this

```
....
OPENJSON(replace(@X, char(10), '\n' ) )  
....
```

Comment: also  in your example case, <....CHAR(10) ,'B"]')>   should read as <....CHAR(10) ,'B"}]')>. I mean it is missing the closing curly bracket

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `CHAR(10)` special character and you may use [STRING_ESCAPE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-escape-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function with `'json'` as second parameter (currently the only possible option) to escape all special characters in the input text:

Statement:

```
DECLARE @X AS VARCHAR(1000) = CONCAT(
  '[{"KEY":1, "VALUE": "A', 
  STRING_ESCAPE(CHAR(10), 'json'),
  'B"}]'
)

SELECT *    
FROM OPENJSON(@X) WITH (
   [KEY] INT 'strict $.KEY',
   [VALUE] VARCHAR(1000) 'strict $.VALUE'
)
```

Result:

```
KEY VALUE
1   A
    B
```