# How to open .ndjson file in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing, ndjson

I have `.ndjson` file that has 20GB that I want to open with Python. File is to big so I found a way to split it into 50 peaces with one online tool. This is the tool: `https://pinetools.com/split-files`

Now I get one file, that has extension `.ndjson.000` (and I do not know what is that)

I'm trying to open it as json or as a csv file, to read it in pandas but it does not work.
Do you have any idea how to solve this?

```
import json
import pandas as pd
```

First approach:

```
df = pd.read_json('dump.ndjson.000', lines=True)
```

Error: `ValueError: Unmatched ''"' when when decoding 'string'`

Second approach:

```
with open('dump.ndjson.000', 'r') as f:

     my_data = f.read() 

print(my_data)
```

Error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 104925061 (char 104925060)`

I think the problem is that I have some emojis in my file, so I do not know how to encode them?

Answer (score 13):

ndjson is now supported out of the box with argument `lines=True`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('/path/to/records.ndjson', lines=True)
df.to_json('/path/to/export.ndjson', lines=True)
```

Comment: *FutureWarning: Passing literal json to 'read_json' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To read from a literal string, wrap it in a 'StringIO' object.*

Comment: In addition to `lines=True`, you should also include `orient="records"`

Answer (score 6):

I think the pandas.read_json cannot handle ndjson correctly.

According to this [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9180) you can do sth. like this to read it.

```py
import ujson as json
import pandas as pd

records = map(json.loads, open('/path/to/records.ndjson'))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
```

P.S: All credits for this code go to KristianHolsheimer from the Github Issue

Comment: In this line: df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records) , 

im getting this error: ValueError: Unmatched ''"' when when decoding 'string'

Comment: Is there any encoding that I need to add, because maybe I have some emojis or special chars in my file?

Comment: One more question about this, is there a way to add some kind of progress bar while I'm uploading this file, because too big and I want to know how much time it left or how much of the file has been uploaded?

Answer (score 3):

The ndjson (newline delimited) json is a json-lines format, that is, each line is a json. It is ideal for a dataset lacking rigid structure ('non-sql') where the file size is large enough to warrant multiple files.

You can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_json('dump.ndjson.000', lines=True)
```

In case your json strings do not contain newlines, you can alternatively use:

```
import json
with open("dump.ndjson.000") as f:
    data = [json.loads(l) for l in f.readlines()]
```

Comment: What if json string will contain a newline? This will break data.

Comment: @Fusion newlines are escaped, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27516892/223301

Answer (score 2):

You can always read it line by line and use a generator to go through the entire file without storing it fully in memory:

```
import json

def batch_read_ndjson(file, batch_size):
    batch = []
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            batch.append(json.load(line))
            if len(batch) == batch_size:
                yield batch
                batch = []

batches = batch_read_ndjson("myfile.ndjson", batch_size=1000)

for batch in batches:
    ## do something
```

That way you can decide how many lines to read in a batch