# Creating local json file in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a Rest JSON server using python and flask as backend and JavaScript as front end, the server data need to be saved in local file but i can't seem to find a way to store the data like :

```py
[
{'id': id, 'name': name},
<--- New record from POST request goes here
]
```

what i mange to do is:

```py
def create(name, title):
    record= str({'id': id, 'name': name}) + '\n'
    rlist= open('static/notes-list.txt', 'a')
    rlist.write(note)
    rlist.close()

# Then for getting data
def get_data():
    f= open('static/notes-list.txt')
    content = f.read()
    f.close()
    data= content.strip().split('\n')
    return data
```

but this give me array of stings in fetch data`['{...}','{...}']

Comment: use databases ?

Comment: sadly i can't its required to be local for this project

Comment: you can use sqlite3 db for this purpose, it will work locally :D

Comment: @JonSG `json.load(f)` resulted in this error ` Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: result is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look like you are storing rows of json ([NDJSON](https://github.com/ndjson/ndjson-spec)). You can use the `json` package to help manage this. There are likely python packages to help manage this type of data structure as well. Check out [How to open .ndjson file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63501251/how-to-open-ndjson-file-in-python) which might ultimately make this post a "*dupe*"

```py
import json

data_file_path = "notes.txt"
id = 1

def create(name, title):
    note= {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "title": title
    }

    with open(data_file_path, "a") as rlist:
        rlist.write(f"{json.dumps(note)}\n")

def get_data():
    with open(data_file_path, "r") as rlist:
        return [json.loads(row) for row in rlist]

create("foo", "bar")
create("foo2", "bar2")

data = get_data()
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

That should result in a file that looks like:

```
{"id": 1, "name": "foo", "title": "bar"}
{"id": 1, "name": "foo2", "title": "bar2"}
```

and data that looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "foo",
        "title": "bar"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "foo2",
        "title": "bar2"
    }
]
```

Comment: The name of this format is NDJSON or JSONLines, btw.

Comment: Thanks, I could not recall the proper name off the top of my head.

Comment: @JonSG Thanks for reply , i ll check and report back after

Comment: @JonSG after checking that was exactly what i needed ty again

Answer (score -2):

Try in get data() putting the f.close() after data= content.strip().spli....

Comment: it does not matter as content already stored in variable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).