# JSON, special characters and sending to database

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

A friend asked me a question, and I wanted to help but finally I thought it is better to expose the problem in order to have advices.

**Situation:** let's say there is a Form, embedding a kind of RichText item: DHTMLX RichText (https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxRichText/).
This RichText allows users to format their texts and the function in the API to retrieve the value of the RichText is sending not only text but also all HTML tags that goes with it.
For example, values like:

```
"<p>TEST </p><p style=" text-align: center;">Line 1<br>Line 2</p><p><strong>END</strong></p>"
```

During the "process" of the Form, the text entered in the RichText is stored in an object like this (for example):

```js
{
   "identifier_1":"id_value_1",
   "identifier_2":"id_value_2",
   "uservalue": "richtextvalue"
}
```

where "richtextvalue" is the value of the RichText .

In addition, it is very possible that people that would use that Form would also copy/paste some texts formatted in Word, and so, we would get any king of other tags from this action.

All this has to be passed to the DB via Ajax/JQuery and/or sent back from the DB to the Form.

**Question:**
What is the best practice in order to "clean" the value from the RichText in order to avoid any trouble and always get a valid JSON string, but also keep the HTML tags?

Currently, I tested with encodeURIComponent / decodeURIComponent, which seemed to work as expected on few tests. But, is it correct or enough?

Thanks!

Comment: just use POST and a text field, i can maybe help but you need to show ajax code

Comment: Neither SQL nor JSON have anything to do with HTML so it doesn't need any special handling. Of course, you always need to generate SQL and JSON properly (that means: no blind string concatenation).

Comment: You may need to escape any `"` in your Rich Text in order for the JSON to be valid. Otherwise, the JSON will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. Meanwhile, I found this topic: [How to escape special characters in building a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string)
with many answers, comment, etc..

In general, I would stick to the logic described in the  accepted answer of this discussion.

Cheers!

Comment: I don’t see how any of that would actually be relevant here - you are not assembling JSON _manually_, are you?