# How to replace “\\” with “\” using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that has an input parameter of $OutputFolder

An example value of $OutputFolder is
'\\\\SHD-D-EDIAPP01\\H2FileRepository\\Dev\\CommonDev\\reports\\HRF605\\'

This is fine for use in JSON to pass to a web service call.

I'm keen to output the folder path in a write-host command that displays the value but with the \\ replaced by \

I have tried this (but it doesn't work):

```
$myOutputFolder = $OutputFolder
$myOutputFolder.Replace("\\\\","\\")
write-host "Parameter OutputFolder is ..... : $myOutputFolder"
```

Any help/guidance/suggestions most appreciated.
If I work out a solution I will reply to own question.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
$myOutputFolder = $OutputFolder.Replace("\\","\")
write-host "Parameter OutputFolder is ..... : $OutputFolder"
write-host "Parameter OutputFolder calc ... : $myOutputFolder"
```

Comment: Yes that’s a string replace. The -replace uses regex so you need to escape the backslash with a backslash. That means for 2 you need another 2 for escaping both. -replace ‘\\\\’,’\’

Answer (score 1):

I guess that somewhere along the line the script that outputs the `$OutputFolder` is misbehaving and directly peeking in a [serialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) Json file.

### General rule:

> Don't peek and/or poke directly in serialized files (as e.g.
> [Json](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) or
> [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) files) using string methods
> (such as `Select-String` and `.Replace`), instead use the related parsers
> (e.g. `[XML]$MyXML`) and/or cmdlets (e.g. `ConvertFrom $MyJson`)

### What's the catch?

In this case, there is a potential pitfall that there are other escaped characters (with a backslash).
Your sample path:

```
'\\SHD-D-EDIAPP01\H2FileRepository\Dev\CommonDev\reports\HRF605\' | ConvertTo-Json
"\\\\SHD-D-EDIAPP01\\H2FileRepository\\Dev\\CommonDev\\reports\\HRF605\\"
```

Although very unlikely in a in a path, Json string values could contain [other escaped characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19176131/1701026):

```
'Hello
"World"' | ConvertTo-Json
"Hello\n\"World\""
```

In other words, to un-escape your Json string, you better do this:

```
$OutputFolder = '\\\\SHD-D-EDIAPP01\\H2FileRepository\\Dev\\CommonDev\\reports\\HRF605\\'
("{""Value"":""$OutputFolder""}" | ConvertFrom-Json).Value
\\SHD-D-EDIAPP01\H2FileRepository\Dev\CommonDev\reports\HRF605\
```

Or just use [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.1) from the start (in your script that has an input parameter of `$OutputFolder`).