# Server error 400 when JSON includes " ' " element in value

Tags: javascript, json, server, frontend

I have a problem sending JSON to the server and getting error in a specific case. I'm not sure if this is a frontend fix or backend, but couldn't find anything online on that.

In case I send:

```
CompanyName: "Bobs company"
```

request goes through, however if I send:

```
CompanyName: "Bob's company"
```

I get an error. Is there a way to fix that problem on frontend?
I get the name by requesting value of the input :

```
  onChange={(e) => {
   setCompanyName(e.target.value);
  }}
```

Comment: Typo in onChange function?

Comment: Use a backslash to escape the single quote.https://stackoverflow.com/q/19176024/4746087

Comment: onChange is badly declared, should read `onChange=((e) => setCompanyName(e.target.value))`

Comment: I understand that ' can be replaced with \ yet, in the input field a person won't type \. Or should I write a function that goes through state and replaces every ' with \

Comment: That's definitely a backend problem

Answer (score 1):

The best way to fix your problem is to change the backend. If you need special characters escape them. In your case the JSON must look like this:

```
{"CompanyName": "Bob\'s company"}
```

Look into the answer from AlexB for more info: [How to escape special characters in building a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string)