# How do i post the RegExpression value in the postman request body

Tags: node.js, json, post, postman, rest

```js
{
    "Regex": "^(Common)[_]\d+$|^(MP)[_][0-9a-f]{24}|.*((google)|(Common)|(gmail))+\.(com)$"
}
```

I am facing the above issue which I mentioned in the screenshot,[image] in postman while I am posting the payload which I provided with RegEx value. It is giving me the Error. Any suggestions guys. Please help out with this issue. Thank you

Comment: Do not post your code, error messages, or other pertinent debugging info as images - instead, paste it as text in the body of your question. Not only is it much easier and can be accomplished in less steps, but it helps when community members can copy and paste your code into another IDE to test it before providing an answer. [ask]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape special characters in building a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string)

Answer (score 2):

Make it simple by adding it in pre-request

```
const regex = JSON.stringify("^(Common)[_]\d+$|^(MP)[_][0-9a-f]{24}|.*((google)|(Common)|(gmail))+\.(com)$")

pm.variable.set("regex",regex)
```

Now call this in body as

```
   {
    "Regex": "{{regex}}"
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it's working like a charm.

Comment: The requirement was different actually Regex value will be always not the same it will be different for different users so it will not going to work..we can not use this env variable..