# Is there a way to replace the JSON value and set it to '' at the same time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a JSON field the looks like this

```
  [{"header":"C", "value": 1"},{"header":"D", "value": 2},{"header":"E", "value": 3}]
```

I want to change the name of the JSON value header and set it to '' but I was only able to change the value.

```
  UPDATE Files SET Columns = REPLACE(Columns, '"header":', '"test":')
```

I want it to look like this:

```
  [{"test":"", "value": 1},{"test":"", "value":2},{"test":"", "value": 3}]
```

Is there a way to set the renamed values to be "" in the REPLACE function?

-EDIT - how do I keep the 2nd value the same while also clearing the first value and changing the name of it?

Comment: In the `REPLACE` function? No. Are there properties other than `"header"` in the original JSON that you need to keep? Seems like you could use `FOR JSON` to generate replacement JSON data.

Comment: Don't change the question after people have posted anwers, it's not appreciated. Make a new question if you have a new problem.

Comment: The \/  is not a problem, it's perfectly valid JSON escaping. When you parse it again using `OPENJSON` or another parser you will see it's gone. You should declare `value int` otherwise you will get `""` quotes around it.

Comment: I don't want the \/ to appear because I am parsing the values and put it into an excel file and it is currently getting the \/ when I just want /. So like 1/10 is expected but I am getting 1\/10 @Charlieface

Comment: As I said, that is standard JSON escaping (which you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27516892/14868997 or many other places). I don't know what parser you are using, but no parser worth it's salt will parse or encode it any other way. You can see also here https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html for example how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to rebuild the JSON using `OPENJSON` to break it open and `FOR JSON PATH` to rebuild it

```sql
UPDATE Files
SET Columns = (
    SELECT test = ''
      -- more properties here
    FROM OPENJSON(Columns)
      WITH (
        header nvarchar(10)
        -- more properties here
      ) j
    FOR JSON PATH
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/9aT5PHiR)

Comment: I made an edit to the JSON and it is taking away the value and replacing it with {"test"='"'}. How do I keep the value as well? @Charlieface

Comment: See edit. You need to add all of the original properties to the select

Comment: I made another edit - when I have 1/10 in as a value, the script changes it to 1\/10 for some reason @Charlieface

Comment: Also that is clearing out the existing tests if I run the script again- is there a way to only run the script only if header exists ?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Json VARCHAR(200)='[{"header":"C"},{"header":"D"},{"header":"E"}]'



SELECT '['+STRING_AGG(JsonVal,',')+']'
FROM (
SELECT A.JsonVal FROM OPENJSON(@Json)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT '{"test":""}' AS JsonVal) A ) J
```