# System.Text.Json Deserialising a String Containing Regex

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

I'm trying to use `System.Text.Json` to work with JSON that contains a string property that contains regex.

```
{
   "urlPattern": "^\/api\/v1\/something\/(.*some-user-id.*)"
}
```

When this is deserialised it ends up being

`"^/api/v1/something/(.*some-user-id.*)"`

The backslashes that were escaping the forward slashes in the regex have been removed. Is there a way to stop this behaviour as it's causing the data to become invalid regex?

Comment: If the backslashes are part of the regex, they need to be escaped as part of the string.

Comment: Looks like you aren't encoding the JSON correctly in the first place. That JSON should probably be `{ "urlPattern": "^\\/api\\/v1\\/something\\/(.*some-user-id.*)" }`

Comment: "_Is there a way to stop this behaviour as it's causing the data to become invalid regex?_" No, because the backslashses are escape tokens in the json string, not part of the actual effective string data. You are basically asking from a Json serializer to behave _not_ as a json serializer.... If you crafted your json manually (as it seems), and a json string has to contain backslashes, you need to escape the backslashes like you would do with double quotes in json string content...

Comment: You don't need to escape the slashes, anyway.  Slashes only need be escaped when they're used as the syntactical boundary for the expression in the language, like in Perl: `if ($path =~ /^\/api\/v1/)` (shortened for simplicity). The same pattern used with the `Regex` class wouldn't need to the slashes escaped because the quotes are the syntactical boundary: `new Regex("^/api/v1")`. JavaScript has both: `/^\/api\/v1/` and `new Regexp("^/api/v1")` are equivalent expressions.

Comment: If you're using the value you get here to generate code that will test that expression, you should produce an escaped version for that language at the point of code generation. `Regex.Escape` can do that for you (if you're generating .NET code). Until then, it's data and should not have anything specific to the language where it will be used.

Comment: How was this JSON created? Looks like you need to fix that instead.

Comment: I can try the double backslash, however it will depend largely on how it is deserialised within the code that the data is being sent to (which isn't .NET) as `^\\/api\\/v1\\/something\\/(.*some-user-id.*)` isn't valid regex

Comment: As shown in the [JSON Standard](https://json.org/), **\/** is the JSON escape sequence for **/**.  So you need to escape every \ in the `"urlPattern"` value as \\.  See [How to escape special characters in building a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19176024), which looks to be a duplicate.

Comment: Also, it looks like the value of "urlPattern" may have been hand-generated. I'd recommend against doing that, and instead use some JSON serializer to format your JSON. If you had, the regex would have been correctly escaped.

Answer (score -1):

Have you try specifying the property as a verbatim string literal?e.g

```
{
   "urlPattern": @"^\/api\/v1\/something\/(.*some-user-id.*)"
}
```

Of course this would have to be done before serialization.

Comment: The `@` prefix on strings is not valid in JSON. JSON is a data exchange format. Verbatim strings are a C# language feature. There's no intersection of the two.

Comment: @madreflection the library serializing the object is a C# library and should have no issues serializing a string literal that represents the value of some property within another C# object either or not the object would eventually be exchanged as a JSON or XML.

Comment: That's patently false. The library isn't processing C# syntax. It's processing JSON, and @ is invalid as a prefix in JSON, plain and simple. The language used has no bearing on that.